# Error in Export in sharepoint 2013

Tags: powershell, sharepoint

I am trying to move a subsite of 100Gb by using Export and import commands. But I am getting error when I try this command

Export-SPWeb http://dc/sites/Coms –Path "//servername/W$Backups/cops.cmp" -IncludeVersions ALL -includeusersecurity

In the above command W is the Drive name and Backups is the folder name in that server. Can anyone help? Is this correct or is there any solution? Thanks

Comment: what error do you get?

Answer (score 0):

Are yo trying to store backup in some other server? In no, then your syntax should be like follow:

```
Export-SPWeb http://dc/sites/Coms –Path "W:\Backups\cops.cmp" -IncludeVersions ALL -includeusersecurity
```

Please refer this MSDN link on export web if you want any more guidance on it:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607895.aspx

Comment: Yes i am trying to store backup in another server

Comment: You need to verify that server is showing in your network path and Backups folder is shared with everyone with write permission.